# how to change values of input field on check box

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Jquery and i've been working on a checkout form. I've placed a check box " Shipping address different from billing address? " and upon checkbox checked the fields are set to empty using the following code.

```
$(document).on('change', '#ship_to_different_address', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $("#fname").val("");
        $("#lname").val("");
        $('#shipping_company').val("");

        this.checked = true;
    }else{

       //What to write here to fetch old values?

    }
});
```

I'm using Laravel framework. Please guide.

Comment: Can you describe what do you want to achieve in short? For example what values do you want to save?

Comment: That's too little information. What exactly is stored where? What do you want to achieve? What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use the checkbox to toggle between clearing the form and restoring the values from before it was cleared.

If you want to be able to fetch the old values, you need to store them somewhere before clearing them.  Here I stash them in a data attribute on each input element, for example:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#ship_to_different_address', function() {
  // Since we're doing the same thing to all three elements, let's make an array loop:
  for (var theId of ['#fname', '#lname', '#shipping_company']) {
    var thisEl = $(theId);
    if (this.checked) {
      thisEl.data("oldval", thisEl.val()) // stash the current value
            .val(""); // clear it
    } else {
      thisEl.val(thisEl.data("oldval")) // retrieve the stash
            .data("oldval",""); // clear the stash
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Fill these:<br>
<input id="fname"><br>
<input id="lname"><br>
<input id="shipping_company"><br> 
Then toggle this:
<input type="checkbox" id="ship_to_different_address">
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are making a checkout form, I think you will need both the shipping and billing address...

So if user select that ***Shipping address is different from billing address*** you will need a shipping address block with same values filled at billing address and if not just empty those fields

```js
$(".radio").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "1") {
    $("#s_fname").val($("#b_fname").val()).prop("disabled", true);
    $("#s_lname").val($("#b_lname").val()).prop("disabled", true);
    $("#shipping_company").val($("#billing_company").val()).prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#s_fname").val("").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#s_lname").val("").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#shipping_company").val("").prop("disabled", false);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Billing address</h4>
<input type="text" id="b_fname" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" id="b_lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input type="text" id="billing_company" placeholder="Company Name" />
<br>
<div style="margin-top:30px;">
  <label><b>Shipping address different from billing address?</b></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" class="radio"/>Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" class="radio"/>No</label>
</div>
<h4>Shipping address</h4>
<input type="text" id="s_fname" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" id="s_lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input type="text" id="shipping_company" placeholder="Company Name" />
```